# Nilpotent elements forming an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Could someone help me to figure out this problem?I am really appreciated it!

Let R be a ring. We say that x belongs to R is nilpotent if there exists n > 0 such that x^n = 0R.
Let R be a commutative ring and let I denote the set of nilpotent elements of R. Prove that if x, y belong to I and r belongs to R, then x+y belongs to I and rx, xr belong to I. [Hint: In order to prove that x+y belongs to I, argue that if a^n = 0 and k is greater than or equal to n, then a^k = 0. You will also need to use the Binomial Theorem.]

Comment: Before posting, spend a few minutes searching to see if it's already out there. Before submitting, spend a few minutes adding context about steps you've taken already, and writing a descriptive title. Even if this question was not a duplicate, it would might get a rough welcome being unformatted and unmotivated.

Comment: Another thing to remember for ring questions is to be specific about when your ring is commutative, when possible. This problem is *not true* for noncommutative rings.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^n=0$ and $y^m=0$ the binomial theorem (in a commutative ring) gives:
 $$(x+y)^{n+m}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{k}x^k y^{n+m-k}$$

So: or $k\ge n$ and $x^k=0$, or $k<n$ and ${n+m-k}>m$ and $y^ {n+m-k}=0$. This implies that $(x+y)^{n+m}=0$ and is nilpotent.

For the second claim note that, if the ring is commutative than $(rx)^n=r^nx^n=0$

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to prove rx,xr belong to I?